# Cordova IOS 8 with Xcode 6 alert box rotating

Tags: cordova, ios8, xcode6, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I am making an application for IOS 8 platform using Xcode 6 & Cordova. I installed a cordova plugin called [org.apache.cordova.dialogs](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.dialogs). I Just lock screen orientation change.Now the problem is that the view is locked and only the alert box is rotating. **I want to prevent this orientation change**.

Comment: show me what you have done?

Comment: Not enough info. What have you tried so far? How did you lock the orientation?